# Select rows with same id that have other data ( search )

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a search function but the current table structure troubles me.

So each row identifies a 'tag' association with an audio ID.

TABLE **audio_tag_assoc** example

[image]

I get the name of each tag id by joining the table tag_association.

TABLE **tag_association** example

[image]

Therefore I need to get all the audio ids that match two or even three tag names.

What I tried is the following but you can probably tell that it doesn't work. I would have later added a join in between those parentheses to change the IDs of the IN with strings.

```
SELECT * 
FROM audio_tag_assoc a 
    JOIN tag_association b ON a.tag = b.id 
WHERE a.audio = (SELECT * 
                FROM audio_tag_assoc 
                WHERE tag IN (2,3)
                )
```

Initially I tried having `b.name = 'Male' AND b.name = 'Film'` but of course, that's not how mysql WHERE clause works.

Comment: Did you mean to OR that as its not possible for the name column to be both Male and Film at the same time`b.name = 'Male' OR b.name = 'Film'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to have two ANDs or three ANDS ( Audio id 3  or any other can have up to 20 tags, therefore I need the audios that match that combination of tags )

Comment: I need a query that matches a combination of tags. For example, I need to get all audios that have tag id 3,4,5,6. If one audio only has tag id 3,4,5 , it should not be a match; in the current screenshot, audio ID 3 would be a match as it has all of the specified tags.

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: @nbk the tables are literally made out of 2 columns, it's more of a theoretical problem, you can clearly see the tables in the post.

Comment: @johnnasx that doesn't make any diffrence even when they had only 1

Answer (score 0):

Do :

```
   SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    audio_tag_assoc
INNER JOIN
    tag_association ON audio_tag_assoc.tag = tag_association.id 
WHERE 
audio_tag_assoc.id IN (SELECT
                    a.id
                FROM audio_tag_assoc a
                WHERE
                    a.tag IN (2,3)
                GROUP BY 
                    a.audio
                HAVING COUNT(a.id) >= 2
                );
```

Comment: Thanks but you probably didn't understand the question. I need a query that matches a combination of tags. For example, I need to get all audios that have tag id 3,4,5,6. If one audio only has tag id 3,4,5 , it should not be a match.

Comment: I update my query, you should somethink like that

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row is my error

Comment: I edited it, try to fix it alone next time, it will be useful to know how to find alone for the future